# Does my CList<BSTR, BSTR> would cause memory leak?

Tags: bstr, clist

```
void CClass::Add(enum MyEnum eMy,BSTR bstring) {

CComBSTR temp(bstring);

switch(eMy)
{
    case e1:
        m_List1.AddTail(temp.Copy()); //m_List1, m_List2, m_List3 are of type CList<BSTR, BSTR>
        break;

    case e2:
        m_List2.AddTail(temp.Copy());
        break;

    case e3:
        m_List3.AddTail(temp.Copy());
        break;

    default:
        break;
      }
 }
```

I am kind of new in COM and MFC and I am not sure whether my piece of code will cause memory problem when I try to remove the element from CList in some other function using RemoveHead() .
Can anyone tell me does my code would cause memory leak or memory corruption?
Thanks in Advance!